# How to delete Custom MetaData Records Via Apex?

Tags: metadata-api, custom-metadata, metadata.operations

I am using `MetaDataService` to create and update Custom Metadata.

I want to also delete records created inside Custom Metadata Type.

I know there is method available to delete metadata like I am using following:

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new  MetadataService.MetadataPort();
MetadataService.DeleteResult [] results = new MetadataService.DeleteResult []{};
results =service.deleteMetadata('CustomMetadata',new List<String>(API_NAME_OF_METADATA));
```

Here we need to provide two arguments to `deleteMetadata` method of `MetadataService`:

1. Type
2. List - List of API Names

I have `Test_MetaData__mdt` and inside that I have 5 records. Now, If I have to delete 5 records of `Test_MetaData__mdt` **which type or what arguments should I provide to `MetadataService` so that I can delete those 5 records?**

`MetaDataService` Delete method

```
public MetadataService.DeleteResult[] deleteMetadata(String type_x,String[] fullNames) {
```

So

```
results =service.deleteMetadata('Which Type?',new List<String>(What Values?));
```

**What values do I need to use for the API Name?** Or is it possible to delete custom metadata records via Apex?

Comment: **Please do not post clarifications  in the comments.** Instead, you should **[edit]** your post to be more clear about what you are asking. I have done so for you here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, It is possible to delete metadata records using `MetadataService.deleteMetadata` method.

Here is a sample method call that should work:

```
List<String> recordsToDelete = new List<String>();
recordsToDelete.add('My_Custom_Type.record1');
service.deleteMetadata('CustomMetadata', recordsToDelete);
```

Where `My_Custom_Type` is the custom metadata type whose record you are trying to delete.

Answer (score 6):

Right now, I don't think it is possible to delete metadata records via **Apex** - only create/update

From the [Trailhead Docs](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_metadata_api/units/apex_metadata_api_intro)

> Although there’s a lot you can do with Apex Metadata API, there are some > limitations to keep in mind.
>
> In the current release, we support only two metadata types: page
> layouts and the records of custom metadata types. Reading, creating,
> and updating metadata are supported, **but deleting metadata is not
> supported**.

The Salesforce Foundation has done a lot of work with Apex and Custom Metadata recently, and their approach was to add a flag to every record called 'Is Deleted', update that to true when a user wanted to mark something as deleted, and then suppress those records when they were being accessed via a query - so basically a custom soft delete. A user can still delete via regular CMD Setup UI if they aren't protected, and /or I think the regular metadata API will still allow deletions

Answer (score -1):

```
public class CreateMetadata implements Metadata.DeployCallback {

    public static void deleteMetadataRecord(String deleteRecord) {
        MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService();
        List<String> recordsToDelete = new List<String>();
        recordsToDelete.add(deleteRecord);
        service.deleteMetadata('CustomMetadata', recordsToDelete);
    }
    
    public static MetadataService.MetadataPort createService() {
        MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
        service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
        service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
        return service;
    }
}

//Here you will fill Metadata object with record developer name To test 
CreateMetadata.deleteMetadataRecord('Metadata_Creditional__mdt.MyTest');
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [answer]. This is very similar to the accepted answer, and contains no explanation. Providing code without an explanation of how it works or why decisions in code were made makes it a _code dump_. Code dumps are of limited value to the community because they don't help people understand why something is broken, and why the fix works. They also tend to generate a lot of back-and-forth in the comments like "that didn't work" and "try this instead" which makes it hard to follow.