Is it possible to delete managed records from a Custom Metadata that have been deployed?
For our 1st generation package we have accidentally deployed records for a particular custom metadata (___md). They are Managed records. So navigating to the metadata records has no "Del" button available.
The environment we use to create packages from shows these records, but it seems there is no possibility to remove these specific records.
Does anyone have information or knows how these records can be deleted from the packaging org?
Many thanks.

Do you have referred to this? -https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deleteMetadata.htm   -https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/229406/how-to-delete-custom-metadata-records-via-apex
